# webview don't display javascript windows.open()

Tags: javascript, android, popup, android-webview

I have a `WebView` in which i display web content which i have no control over. The content displays fine, but have links which spawn a popup window. The javascript function that does that looks like this:

```
function getEntry(id) {
var win = window.open('', 'Booking',
'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=500,height=400');
win.document.location = '/some/url/1-' + id ;
}
```

I can't easily change this, and if the people responsible for the page i download would change it, i guess my app would fail miserably...

My `WebView` setup in the activity looks like this:

```
    _webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(_webview);

    final Activity activity = this;
    _chromeClient = new MyChromeClient();

    _webview.setWebChromeClient(_chromeClient);

    //I experimented with changing user agent, in case that would have any effect, it didn't...
    _webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");

    _webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    _webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    _webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    _webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    _webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    _webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    //Cache settings...
    _webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
    _webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/com.your.package.appname/cache");
    _webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    _webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

MyWebClient:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("MyWebViewClient",url);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        showProgressDiag();
        Log.d("MyWebViewClient","shouldOverride... : " + url);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        hideProgressDiag();
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        if(failingUrl.equals("file:///android_asset/html/error.html")){
            hideProgressDiag();
            Toast.makeText(_context, "Error! Check internet connection, or try again later...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(_context, failingUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/error.html");
        }

    }

}
```

MyChromeClient:

```
private class MyChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     Pdiag.setProgress(progress * 100);
    }

}
```

When clicking one of the links that points to the javascript function all that happens is that the `WebView` turns grey, without going through `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. When i hit the back key the app exits, meaning that nothing was placed in the nav history of the `WebView`. Sometimes nothing happens, but then the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` **do run** and from a `Log.d()` i can see that the correct URL for the popup has been given to the WebView.

The thing is, on very rare occasions it shows up fine, but i have no clue how to reproduce it, and wether it actually shows in a popup.

I'm lost... And quite frustrated... Thinking of watching a bad sitcom instead :(

**EDIT:**
Actually, maybe the URL wasn't all that correct after all... In Firefox the URL ends with "X<<<<" but in my Log.d() output it ends with "X%3C%3C%3C%3C"... I'll investigate if i could change that...

**EDIT 2:**
Nope, didn't do anything... The URL is identical to the one in Firefox...

Comment: It does look like those type of javascript url changes don't reliably call shouldOverrideUrlLoading. Maybe there is a workaround or a hackish way of solving your problem. Let's say it was able to be caught normally, what are you trying to do with it once you catch it?

Comment: At the moment I don't do anything. Yesterday it opened just fine. It doesn't look like a floating popup, but at least it showed up. But since the script produces the correct url, ideally I'd just grab that url and do a loadUrl() with it. But if that works, how do I stop it from loading twice, manually by me and automatically by the webview? And where do I intercept the url? In on LoadResource()?

Comment: If you don't override shouldOverrideUrlLoading() or only return false in it, does it load properly?  What is the problem?  Is it because it isn't in the back button history when it loads this way?

Comment: I'll check what happens if I don't override shouldOver...(). The problem is that 80% of the times I click the link, the only thing happening is the webview turns grey (possibly my bgcolor, I'll try changing that to a funkier color to verify that), 10% of the times nothing happens, although onLoadRes...() gets called with the correct url, and the remaining 10% of the clicks gives the correct result, albeit not in a floating popup as the standard browser shows it.

Comment: I'll be able to try your suggestion in am hour our so. I just don't understand why webview should behave differently from the browser. It works perfectly in the browser, so why should I have to hack the html when I don't want to change either the content or the way it shows. I keep having a feeling that it is just something stupid, like having setJavascriptCanOpenWindows() on the wrong line or something...

Comment: Nope, it's the same behaviour even without overriding the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method. I did however find out how to get the webview to show the problematic content. If i click the link, it turns grey, but if i then do a refresh (which loads the previously shown page) and yet again click the link it shows! Quite annoying though to have to ask the user to go through this procedure every time he wishes to see the popup...

Answer (score 16):

First of all, you need to set the following settings on your `WebView`:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

Then you need to attach a `WebChromeClient` that overrides `onCreateWindow`. Your implementation of this method can create a new web view, and display it inside a dialog:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            WebView newWebView = new WebView(MyActivity.this);
            WebSettings webSettings = newWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            // Other configuration comes here, such as setting the WebViewClient

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(newWebView);
            dialog.show();

            newWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            ((WebView.WebViewTransport)resultMsg.obj).setWebView(newWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();
            return true;
        }

});
```

Don't forget to set the new web view to the `resultMsg`, send it to its target and return true, as mentioned in [the API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onCreateWindow(android.webkit.WebView,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20android.os.Message)).

Comment: I would like to add the following code: 
    ...
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(newWebView);
            dialog.show();
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
           newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    ....
This makes a fullscreen dialog, and makes it open inside your webview.

Comment: Kudos to you bro, just saved my day. Creating window is handled so gracefully that it works with payment methods and automatic closing. Thanks to you bro

Answer (score 1):

Please check with adding this -

```
    getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

Comment: Geez, thanks! I will check that. Don't know when i will find time though. It's not my most active project nowadays... When i try it, and if it works I'll mark your solution! I promise!