# Android webview crash "Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP)"

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

I have an app with a web view in which I load HTML content with JavaScript enabled. The web view is inside a fragment.

This is how I initialize the web view inside the method `onCreateView` of the fragment :

```java
WebView webview = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview);

WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        /*
        * My code
        */
    }
});

webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
        String data = result.getExtra();
        if (data != null) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
        return false;
    }
});

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

In the web view, a map is loaded with JavaScript. On this map, we can click on elements and load photos. When clicked, the photo is displayed in a popup (still inside the web view). When I click on the back button to go back to the map, the app crashes.

[image: GIF of the crash in app]

Here is the error log :

> A/libc: Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 in tid 949 (Chrome_InProcRe)
> [ 03-21 11:26:08.510   364:  364 W/         ]
> debuggerd: handling request: pid=32610 uid=10289 gid=10289 tid=949

I tested and got the crash on Android 7.1.1, 6.0.1, 5.0.2. Then I tried with Android 4.4.2 and the app didn't crash.

When I click on the back button (as we can see on the GIF), it should go back to the previous state with the popup closed

Comment: do you test on device or emulator? please set an webchromeclient before loadDataWithBaseUrl() like this: webview .setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Comment: And for Javascript debbugging it's good to override onConsoleMessage in WebChromeClient

Comment: @user2281606 It works fine on emulator. Also, I was already setting a webchrome client. I edited the code in my question.
I tried to see the logs with remote debugging https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews but there is no logs

Comment: i don't see onConsoleMessage, i only see overwritten onCreateWindow method ? Please override it an look for javascript logs

Comment: @user2281606 Remote debugging does the exact same thing, in fact I have one log but it is not related to my problem : 
`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://livemap.getwemap.com//iframe.php?emmid=3120&token=at539f0844468d33.32940855' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://webdev.maaap.it/proxima/images/powered_by_wemap.svg'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. -- From line 0 of https://livemap.getwemap.com//iframe.php?emmid=3120&token=at539f0844468d33.32940855`

Comment: Did you ever solve this @Eddybrtn? I'm seeing the same. I think it relates to hardware acceleration being enabled, because when I disable hardware acceleration these crash reports disappear... but then my "slow rendering" metric goes through the roof... stuck between a rock and a hard place :-(

Comment: @drmrbrewer I guess we'll never know

Comment: This one helped me to resolve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/43721647/2963385

Comment: Strong recommend - Always do webview work with the chrome debugger (android) or safari debugger (ios)

Answer (score 1):

Try to override the back navigation functionality and close the popup yourself.

You don't need to handle all the stack navigation logic, just have a state when you are showing this popup.
Apply your own navigation logic(like manually closing the popup).

```
void onBackPressed(){
    if(isTheBuggyPopupIsOn){
        closeTheBuggyPopup();
    }
    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

First add this

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
```

and then add this

```
public class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (url.equals(""YOUR URL)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: It's not working, the callback does not catch the click. Do you have further explanation please ?