# stop loading in webViewClient

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

In my WebView, I have multiple links in header. In Offline mode, I mustn't allow reload the page and keep that page as is and then, inform users about internet connection. I am able to catch links before it loads using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` if I click other links. But if I click the same link, `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not being fired, instead, `onLoadResource` method is being called first. In that method I tried `webView.stopLoading();` but it continues working and fire `onReceivedError` method and shows error report on the page.

Here is my WebClient:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(MyApplication.getInstance().isOnline()) {
                return false;
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check Internet connection and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.i("ON_PAGE_START", "RUNNING ============>" + url);
            if (MyApplication.getInstance().isOnline()) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            } else {
                webView.stopLoading();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) { 

            if (MyApplication.getInstance().isOnline()) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            } else {
                webView.stopLoading();                  
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {               

            view.stopLoading();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check Internet connection and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);    
        }
    });
```

What I want is to be able to ensure that urls are not being fired if it is offline and inform about that.

Comment: Anybody looking for Kotlin solution. you just need to keep `onLoadResource` function empty `override fun onLoadResource(view: WebView?, url: String?) {}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a known issue and there is a bug reported for it.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2887

A number of workarounds have been suggested. e.g.

1. [Override onPageStarted](http://www.catchingtales.com/android-webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-and-redirect/416/)
2. [Add JavascriptInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129877/2107118) by CommonsWare
3. [Disable WebView touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3856199/2107118)

Additionally, register a BroadcastReceiver to listen to network state changes and apply the workaround when the connectivity is lost. 
[Network listener Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Well, for **1**, as you can see in my code above, I did override `onPageStarted`and tried `stopLoading()` with no success. **2**,  I actually thought about that, but in my case it might be _dangerous_ to relying on `<a>` tag since server could change the structure of the page. But the **3rd** really charmed me. How didn't it come to my mind, I don't know :). I 'll try it next week, and let you know, and possibly mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Hello, I think I cannot disable touch event, because I have to cache one of the pages and load in in offline mode. If I disable touch events, then I won't be able to load it, or what? We came up with one specific idea which is not very good, but adequate to our needs for the moment. Thanks again

Comment: @boburShox: Please share the idea

Comment: So, I cache the page first. In case there's no Internet, I load the cached data with `loadDataWithBaseURL`, of course, I check whether there is cached data or not. One drawback is that users can notice the  web view complaining about the network and load the data.

Answer (score 4):

I think in onLoadRessource(..) and onPageStarted() it further should be

```
view.stopLoading();
```

in your else{..}

Answer (score 1):

I know its quite an old post but thanks for this post, this helped me solve the issue!!!

I had a similar issue and stopLoading solved my issue :)

shouldOverrideUrlLoading gets called if it goes to a new page or if there is a redirection but not otherwise like for ex clicking on iframe etc. I wanted to achieve the similar behaviour in my app, and i realised that onPageStarted is called but not shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

I didn't override onLoadResource but just onPageStarted since onLoadResource gets called after onPageStarted. OnPageStarted checks if offline and not to load in that case. hope this helps someone.